# Is define setter and getter in .h cause codes more or less readable?

Tags: c++, coding-style, inline, setter, getter

I have some straight habits (I think) to write getter and setter in c++:

1. I usually like to define getters and setters in .h instead of .cpp, just because I think .cpp usually have more codes than .h, I want to balance the number of codes in .h and .cpp. Also I think getter and setter are less frequent change than other functions.
2. I usually mark getters and setters "inline", but not for performance purpose: just only use "inline" as marker of getter and setter, when I see "inline" I can know it is a getter or a setter method rapidly. So I will prevent "inline" other methods because "inline" is just use as marker to separate getter and setter from other methods.

But after some time, I found seems no people would put getter and setter in .h. Also it seems uncommon to inline getters and setters.

Is the habit really improve readability or only results in less understandable and less reasonable code?

Comment: _"I want to balance the number of codes in .h and .cpp."_ That doesn't really make much sense as far as goals go.

Comment: Definition of method inside the class are `inline`, so it seems that you can omit `inline` keyword for your getter/setter (except if you define your method outside (/after) the class).

Answer (score 2):

> I usually like to define getters and setters in .h instead of .cpp, just because I think .cpp usually have more codes than .h, I want to balance the number of codes in .h and .cpp.

Is there any specific reason to do so? You have to **write code where it should be** not according to a (questionable) aesthetic sense of *balance*. Moreover a very short heavily used header file and a long compilation unit **may** result in reduced overall compilation time.

> Also I think getter and setter are less frequent change than other functions.

This makes sense to **reduce compilation time** if header is included in many other compilation units however don't abuse this, compilation time is important but code readability is more. Worry about this only if you're using a very old computer or you're working on a huge project.

> I usually mark getters and setters "inline", but not for performance purpose: just only use "inline" as marker of getter and setter, when I see "inline" I can know it is a getter or a setter method rapidly. So I will prevent "inline" other methods because "inline" is just use as marker to separate getter and setter from other methods.

**Absolutely bad**! `inline` is to give an hint to compiler to inline that method, do not use it for something else! Would you use (let's imagine) `volatile` to *highlight* variables used only in `const` functions? Use language constructs for what they're for. Always.

> But after some time, I found seems no people would put getter and setter in .h.

**Any evidence** of this?

> Also it seems uncommon to inline getters and setters.

*Maybe* not explicitly (because nowadays `inline` is more an hint for other programmers than for compiler) but they're **good candidates to become inlined** because they're usually simple and call overhead is higher than code they execute. Don't worry where you put them, if compiled detects it'll improve your code performance (in speed or memory footprint) it'll make them inline without your help (but you may force it to do it or don't do it using some vendor specific extensions).

> Is the habit really improve readability or only results in less understandable and less reasonable code?

In my opinion (that's I marked this answer as community wiki) it's a **bad habit** because no one else but you will understand your reasoning. It's astonishing: if I see a method explicitly marked as `inline` I expect a performance critical method (and `inline` make it evident) and *astonishing code* is error prone code.

I'm especially against inline used to mark getter/setter methods, pick a good coding convention and make it your. It'll evolve with your own (or your company) coding style and your experience but don't reinvent the wheel before you first master existing stuff...

Answer (score 1):

1. you can define it in .h files and that doesn't imply on code readability if they are short. int getX() const { return _x; }
   if this functions are complex - maybe you should avoid that.
2. setter are usually more complex, thats why you should move to .cpp files.
3. about inline:

   - don't care about it before optimisation step of development.
   - functions in .h doesn't inline automatically, even inline word is just recommendation for compiler. (different compilers have __force_inline word)
4. you should read some code styles, for example google C++ code style or some other and grab some rules there.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't care about inline at all.  Most modern compilers know when to inline and when not far better than any programmer can.

Comment: yep, I'm absolutly agree with you - first & main goal is to achieve correct behaviour & code code readability, because it will made support and refactoring easier.

Answer (score 0):

Marking functions defined inside the class definition `inline` is redundant because those functions will be inlined by default anyway.

Only if you define a function outside the class in a header file, should the definition be marked `inline`.

Also it's common to define simple one-liners such as getters and setters in the class definition, don't worry about it. Just automatically put all one-line functions there, it's the common practice.

You can quickly see which ones are getters and setters from their `get` or `set` prefix, and also from the fact that their definitions are very short. It might also help to group them together physically.

Answer (score 0):

1. Although it is common to put getters and setters in header files I would say it is not good practice. If you need to change these functions at all or if they need to become more complicated than a single line function then all compilation units using that header need to be recompiled. Just make a rule of only having function definitions in .cpp files and compile with LTCG or LTO enabled if you are worried that they will no longer be inlined by the compiler.
2. Although historically the [`inline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) keyword could be a hint to the compiler to inline the body of the function all modern compilers I know of ignore it when deciding how to best optimise. Its only modern usage is to declare an *inline* function, that is one that can be present in multiple compilation units without violating the one definition rule. This is a linkage concept and a separate idea to the concept of an *inlined* function although given the past multiple usage of the keyword the confusion is understandable. All functions declared within a class or struct definition are *implicitly* inline functions and therefore there is no need to explicitly use the `inline` keyword.